# created images not recognized in android gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery, jpeg

I'm creating an app that creates and saves images. Currently I am saving them to /sd_card/my_app_name/. The files are there and everything, but they are not recognized from the Android's gallery. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

well, I figured this out quickly enough :

```
try {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filePath, "image name", "image dexscription");  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: are you referring to the native Gallery app or the Gallery view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is this:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filePath, image name, details);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to make every new change recognized.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

I think this will resolve your issue.